# R - using the assign() function for subsetting an array

Tags: r, assign

I have tried to get the gist of my problem in the following reproducible example :

```
mat <- matrix(3:6,nr=2,nc=2)
j=1
> eval(parse(text=paste0("m",c("a","b")[j],"t","[1,1]")))
[1] 3
> assign(paste0("m",c("a","b")[j],"t","[1,1]"),45)
> mat
      [,1] [,2]
[1,]    3    5
[2,]    4    6
```

My problem is that `mat[1,1]` is still equal to `3` and not `45` as I would have expected.

Comment: I think it will really help for us to understand WHY you would like to use `assign()` in this fashion.

Comment: I am trying to increment an array with a changing name.

Comment: I am almost sure you can't use `assign()` in this way, because `assign()` operates on names. The name of the matrix is just `mat` or whatever. The rest of the stuff, namely, the `[`, is actually a function in R.

Comment: Read also http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Functions.html

Comment: That explains it then. Thank you.

Comment: I am going to turn my comment into an answer, in case other users find this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A primer on R: ["Every operation is a function call."](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Functions.html) What this means, in a practical sense for your question, is that you can't use `assign()` with more than just a name. mat[1,1] is not a name - it is the name `mat` and the function call `[`. So, using the expression `mat[1,1]` within `assign` will not work, because it is trying to find an R object named `mat[1,1]` (which I think is disastrous for a few reasons...)

This seems like a really weird use case. You might want to consider instead working in a function, which has its own environment that you can manipulate without working in the global environment.

Alternatively, you can do this:

```
eval(parse(text=paste0("m",c("a","b")[j],"t","[1,1] <- 45")))
eval(parse(text=paste0("m",c("a","b")[j],"t","[1,1]")))
```

I am struggling to think of a reason you would want to - but it is, in theory, possible. Basically, you just add the assignment to the text that you are parsing, then pass it to `eval()`.